# How to run a Header directive for the root only from .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, http-headers

I have Apache 2.4.18 (security patched) but due to hosting restrictions I can't change the configuration files only `.htaccess`. `mod_headers` is enabled and I would like to run a `Header` directive only when `www.example.com/` is accessed (with or without trailing slash). `LocationMatch '^/$'` is not allowed in `.htaccess`. Now what?

Answer (score 1):

You could do this (untested)

```
 Header always set CustomHeader my-value "expr=%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/+$#"
```

Something similar is detailed in Apache docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html